# Automating CSS animation restart through loop and DOM

Tags: javascript, css, dom

I'm trying to restart a CSS animation, so that they can be played in order from an array. I'm using the setTimeout method for that.

So far, I've managed to successfully restart the animation, that is, play the same animation repeatedly when I call the animation function manually.

I have also managed to play different animations in succession using a loop (e.g.: Green, then Blue etc..), but when I try using the loop and the animation restart together, so that the same button can be triggered twice (Green, then Green again), it doesn't work.

**Loop:**

```
var listOfRandomButtons = ["green", "green", "green"];

var i = 0;

function myLoop() {

  setTimeout(function() {

    if (listOfRandomButtons[i] === "green") {
      greenAnimation();
    };

    if (listOfRandomButtons[i] === "red") {
      redAnimation();
    };

    if (listOfRandomButtons[i] === "yellow") {
      yellowAnimation();
    };

    if (listOfRandomButtons[i] === "blue") {
      blueAnimation();
    };

    i++;

    if (i < listOfRandomButtons.length) {
      myLoop();
    };

  }, 2000)
};

myLoop();
```

**Restart:**

```
function greenAnimation() {

  document.getElementById("green").classList.toggle("greenPressed");

  setTimeout(function() {

    document.getElementById("green").classList.toggle("greenPressed");

  }, 1001);

}
```

Comment: `if (i < listOfRandomButtonsLength)` should be `if (i < listOfRandomButtons.length)`

Comment: Thanks, that was fast! I've corrected it but it's not the issue. I had a variable somewhere else in the document for it.

Comment: How is the animation itself defined with the class `greenPressed`? Can you provide a code example?

Comment: The animation is basically a CSS animation on a class, like:

`.greenPressed {
  background-color: green;
  animation: greenPressed 1s;
}

@keyframes greenPressed {
 0% {background-color: green;}
 50% {background-color: white;}
 100% {background-color: green;}
} `

Answer (score 0):

listOfRandomButtonsLenght was indeed set as a variable for listOfRandomButtons.lenght somewhere else in the document, but before the variable for listOfRandomButtons had been defined. Thanks @ptothep